# Pegar somente uma parte do conteúdo do input sem submeter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Estou criando uma galeria de imagens utilizando o plugin responsivefilemanager e surgiu um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Vejam essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão azul (Com o simbolo da pasta) é aberta uma Modal na qual eu consigo criar pastas, realizar upload de imagens etc.
Quando eu seleciono a pasta, a tela fecha e o caminho da pasta é retornado no Input, mas estou tendo dificuldade em tratar isso, pq na verdade eu queria somente o final da URL (nome da pasta).

Por isso pergunto, como posso resolver essa situação? Preciso obter o valor sem submeter então não posso usar `$_GET` ...

Aqui está o código do meu botão

```
<div class="col-xs-4  col-md-4">
    <label for="pasta">Pasta:</label>
    <!-- Campo Pasta e Seleção de Imagens-->
    <div class="input-group">
        <span clas="input-group-btn text-center">
            <a href=<?=(Empty($dir))?"/assets/libs/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=folder": "/".$dir."/assets/libs/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2?type=2&field_id=folder"?> class="btn btn-info fancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>
            </a>
        </span>                                     
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pasta" class="form-control" name="folder" id="folder" onchange="buscar('medium')" value="">   
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Você esta selecionar o diretório inteiro ? Ou arquivo ?

Comment: Diretório inteiro ! Abs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao realizar a escolha do arquivo, você pode utilizar a seguinte function callback para processar as alteraões que deseja realizar:

```
function responsive_filemanager_callback(field_id){
    console.log(field_id);
}
```

Outra opção seria você utilizar o callback do fechamento do modal fancybox.

```
    $("<YOUR-SELECTOR>").fancybox({ 
        afterClose: function() { 
        // adicionar aqui o tratamento para pegar o nome do arquivo e adicionar no campo 
        }) 
    });
```

Comment: Estou usando o funcybox pra modal

Comment: @DiegoLela voce pode fazer no seu script, adicionar uma acao apos salvar 
$("<YOUR-SELECTOR>").fancybox({
  afterClose: function() {
     // adicionar aqui o tratamento para pegar o nome do arquivo e adicionar no campo
  })
});

Comment: obrigado amigo! funcionou abraços